# Beginning document on a page number other than "1"

Tags: page-numbering

How do we create a new document starting on different pages? (Such as the first page of the document starts on 3 instead of 1.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question: you want the first page of your document to have the pagenumber 3,then it can be simply done with a `\setcounter{page}{3}`, at the begin of your document body (right after `\begin{document}`)